# Why does the Component Presentation Assembler not execute JSP code?

Tags: content-delivery, broker, jsp, dynamic

We're busy upgrading to Web 8.5, and I'm having some problems with JSP Dynamic Component Presentations. These are correctly deployed to disk, and the `ComponentPresentationFactory` is able to locate my test DCP. However, when I invoke the `ComponentPresenationAssembler` like this:

```
ComponentPresentationAssembler componentPresentationAssembler 
                                 = new ComponentPresentationAssembler(127); 
out.write(componentPresentationAssembler.getContent(513988, 243136));
```

then I get the same output as if I invoke the `ComponentPresentationFactory` like this:

```
com.tridion.dcp.ComponentPresentationFactory cpf 
                                = new com.tridion.dcp.ComponentPresentationFactory(127);
com.tridion.dcp.ComponentPresentation cp = cpf.getComponentPresentation(513988, 243136);
out.write(cp.getContent());
```

In other words, what I see is the raw JSP code, and not the rendered output that I expected.

When I call `cp.isDynamic()`, the result is `false`, although I don't know whether that is significant. In the Broker database I can see that the `TEMPLATE_OUTPUT_FORMAT` of the Component Template is, as expected, `JSP Scripting`.

What can cause this? Where should I be looking to get some insight into this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ComponentPresentationAssembler needs access to your page context to work, so the constructor overload that accepts just the publication id won't work. You need to instantiate a JSPPage with the pageContext and pass that in.

```
com.tridion.web.jsp.JSPPage dcdPage 
                         = new com.tridion.web.jsp.JSPPage(pageContext, "tcm:127-507637-64");
ComponentPresentationAssembler componentPresentationAssembler 
                             = new ComponentPresentationAssembler(dcdPage);
```

(I'd changed the constructor in my test case while solving a different problem.)